# Can I get help solving this indefinite integral: (tan(x))^2*(sec(x))^1/2

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I am quite stuck on how do I solve this indefinite integral, the integrand is: (tan(x))^2(sec(x))^1/2; I got it as a residue of a differential equation I was solving, I tried a lot of substitutions but they only make it more and more complicated, I tried to convert tangent into secant to obtain a better integral but it only gets more and more complicated.

Apologies for I uploaded the integrand in this manner for I am still a beginner and learning how to use Latex, or MathJax.

Comment: I edited my answer: I had a pretty significant error, but I fixed it. I'm going to add more though

Comment: I found out that my last edit had an error, so I fixed it and added a substantial bit to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Maple and [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+tan(x)%5E2*sec(x)%5E(1%2F2)) agree that the antiderivative involves elliptic integrals.  Elementary techniques will not work.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Find out that $$\int_0^x\tan^2(t)\sec^{1/2}(t)dt=\int\tan^2(x)\sec^{1/2}(x)dx$$

Then express everything in the integrand in terms of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ raised to powers, then apply
$$\int_0^x\sin^{a}(t)\cos^{b}(t)dt=\frac12B\bigg(\sin^2x;\frac{a+1}{2},\frac{b+1}{2}\bigg)$$
Where $B(x;h,k)$ is the [Incomplete Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function).

EDIT:

Here's how you derive that identity I gave you.
$$I(x,a,b)=\int_0^x\sin^{a}(t)\cos^{b}(t)dt$$
The substitution $u=\sin^2(t)$ gives 
$$I(x,a,b)=\frac12\int_{0}^{\sin^2x}u^{\frac{a-1}2}(1-u)^{\frac{b-1}2}du$$
$$I(x,a,b)=\frac12\int_{0}^{\sin^2x}u^{\frac{a+1}2-1}(1-u)^{\frac{b+1}2-1}du$$
Then one must recall the primary definition for the incomplete Beta function
$$B(x;h,k)=\int_0^xt^{h-1}(1-t)^{k-1}dt$$
Of course this gives our integral:
$$I(x,a,b)=\frac12B\bigg(\sin^2x;\frac{a+1}2,\frac{b+1}2\bigg)$$